# Selenium Fails with Chrome Version 32.0.1700.72 m

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, .net-4.5, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome automatically updated to "Version 32.0.1700.72 m" for me this morning (1/8/2014) and now all my automated tests will not run--they fail with "System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages" almost immediately.

I'm running:

- Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1) 64-bit
- Chrome Version 32.0.1700.72 m
- Selenium ChromeDriver v2.2
- .NET C#

This is the console output that I get:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.2) on port 26819
[8668:8300:0108/162344:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8668:8300:0108/162344:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8668:8300:0108/162345:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Class Initialization method LeadManager.Web.UITest.Tests.ViewLeads.PriorityModeTests.ClassInitialize threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64).
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 1012
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 846
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 814
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 89
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver.cs: line 101
   at UITestFramework.Providers.WebDriverProvider.CreateWebDriver(TestSettings settings) in WebDriverProvider.cs: line 73
   at UITestFramework.Domain.TestSettings..ctor(BrowserType browserType, String baseUrl) in TestSettings.cs: line 69
   at LeadManager.Web.UITest.Tests.SettingsFactory.GetSettings() in SettingsFactory.cs: line 33
   at LeadManager.Web.UITest.Tests.ViewLeads.PriorityModeTests.ClassInitialize(TestContext context) in PriorityModeTests.cs: line 38
```

So the ChromeDriver constructor call is failing.

Anyone else seeing same issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Was anyone anyone able to get this to work for mac?

We're running into the same problem but when grabbing the latest chromedriver 2.8 from here:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.8/

Is showing version 2.4. Also, still running into this problem even with this chromedriver version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is common when Chrome/Firefox updates, ChromeDriver/Selenium always need to catch up.

However, the latest ChromeDriver should support Chrome 32 already. Your situation is because you are using way out of date ChromeDriver 2.2. Please use the latest version 2.8, you can download it [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.8/).

Otherwise if you need to keep ChromeDriver 2.2, you can also downgrade your Chrome to your old version.

Comment: Thanks for the link. :)  Problem solved for Windows 7!

Comment: I encountered the same problem! how can I check, which version of ChromeDriver I am running. Also after downloading the latest version of ChromeDriver, where should I copy it into ? Thanks!

Comment: @ManiAm: Have a look here for how to use it. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: @user1177636 I'm having this issue on Windows, and I have lastest Chrome and Chromedriver 2.9. Tests run, but I get all the NOT IMPLEMENTED errors

Comment: @user699242: That's just the console output from ChromeDriver, which does't indicate anything wrong with the tests.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across the same issue;
And resolved by updating ChromeDriver from 2.4 to 2.8

Answer (score 2):

For our project, we use npm. I resolved the same issue by removing the node_modules\chromedriver, then running:

```
npm install chromedriver
```

Comment: For future reference you should be able to avoid having to remove it and just call `npm update chromedriver`, it should take care of everything for you. Here is the documentation for that particular call: https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-update.html

Answer (score 1):

Chrome updates happen often and not all updates will necessarily work with a particular version of chromedriver. Take control by installing the Google gpeditor admin templates and turn on the Google Chrome update policy. This way you can control and test your updates as required for both chrome and chromedriver. Note it is best to update chrome as soon as possible.

[WikiHow shows you!](http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update)

This is the approach I have taken since chrome 27 and chromedriver 2.1. Works well and keeps the integrity of your tests.