# Selenium ChromeDriver won't start on any Windows OS

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I created a program that requires ChromeDriver.

It works fine on Mac OS X and Linux, but when I try to start it on Windows it hangs on the following:

```
"driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);"
```

However no error is generated.

I have loaded the chrome driver correctly and I set the binary path to chrome.exe correctly.  for some unknown reason it just hangs when initializing the driver.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("window-size=800,600");
    options.setBinary(getChromePath()); //Returns Chrome Path (Works)

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have no idea why this is happening and chromedriver.exe is never even started up as a process. This doesn't work with any Windows computers, but works with every other operating system.

Comment: Selenium is 2.39 and ChromeDriver is 2.8

Comment: Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `capabilities`, would it start normally?

The following answer might not be related to your problem. Debug yours first, then try it if you don't have other solutions.

Chrome have been updating frequently recently and you need to find a ChromeDriver version compatible with it.

The latest Chrome release is `2.8`, according to [release note](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.8/notes.txt), it should support Chrome `30-33`.

However, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21009568/1177636), I believe the recent Chrome updates broke it again.
Chrome `32.0.1700.72 m` should work fine with ChromeDriver `2.8`, but `32.0.1700.76` and `32.0.1700.77` won't.

So try two solutions at the time of writing.

1. Downgrade your Chrome to `32.0.1700.72 m` or even lower.
2. Since ChromeDriver `2.8` is already the latest, all you can do is to wait for a new version to come out, which should be on its way.

Comment: However, it does work on Mac OS X and that is the same chrome version... I will still try to downgrade though.

Comment: Also, where can I get an older version of Chrome if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @user3190757: It's not only because version number dismatch but also about what's actually inside. Mac OS X uses Mac version Chrome, Mac version ChromeDriver. Windows uses different ones. If one windows machine works, but another windows doesn't work, then in that case what you think makes sense, because only one factor changes.

Comment: @user3190757: Google gives me [this](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php) for old versions.

Comment: Ok, well how could I downgrade to Chrome with it not updating back again?

Comment: @user3190757: Uninstall your Chrome and install the old one. For how to disable auto update, could you please Google "chrome auto update disable" and find one solution suits you.

Comment: I just decided to use Firefox instead as it is much more portable temporarily. I will use FirefoxDriver on windows and ChromeDriver on everything else.

Comment: @user3190757: Yes, you can do that. But warning ahead, Firefox might face the same situation whenever it updates, which breaks Selenium normally more frequently than Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium requires English windows operating system. Otherwise it doesnt trigger any browser. When I changed my windows 10 turkish version to english it started working without any problem. If you are having the same issue with both IE, gecko driver and chrome driver than the issue is definiately this one.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the latest version of chrome 32.0.1700.76 m......means you have to update the chrome driver server also that is 2.8...and selenium 2.39

Answer (score 0):

check this line: 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

you are working with chrome and there is still firefox to which capabilities refer to.